# good way to create margin to the top for the first element

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

I have list that I render with [semantic-ui](/questions/tagged/semantic-ui) and it needs some margin to the top for the first element. I looked in the CSS code and I see `margin-top:0!important` and I can override it for the first element with `margin-top:10px!important;` and then the rendering looks good. Is there a better way to achieve it? My code (without the fix) is

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.2/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav active"><a href="#A" data-toggle="tab">All</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav"><a href="#B" data-toggle="tab">Company</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav"><a href="#C" data-toggle="tab">Private</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="A">
      <div class="ui divided items">
        <div class="item">
          <div class="ui left floated">
            7 July.
            <br>3:33
          </div>
          <div class="image">
            <a href="/vi/5022701123010560.html">
              <img src="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/JZkr-b_aWlYrFG1G-EUywZgucJE3JV1wgz4yQGrx-bGaw_va7dymsaTMXhK5t6ZkUdjWLeHlNaiksVNAMp8I1epB-Q=s150" title="Wordpress development company, website developer" alt="Wordpress development company, website developer">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="content">
            <a class="header" href="/vi/5022701123010560.html">Wordpress development company, website developer</a>
            <div class="meta">
              <span class="price"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="description">
              <p>Dit Interactive have experts wordpress ...</p>
            </div>
            <div class="extra">
              <div class="ui label">
                Services
              </div>
              <div class="ui label">
                For sale
              </div>
              <div class="ui label">Central NJ</div>
              <div class="ui label">New Jersey</div>
              <div class="ui right floated primary button">
                Buy now
                <i class="right chevron icon"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="ui left floated">
            7 July.
            <br>0:54
          </div>
          <div class="image">
            <a href="/vi/5870511561113600.html">
              <img src="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/rsfBseoSy-KPg6P703Dknbpd0t2Ug4n2BY8oKkg2XH5dkufstmZXMWSCsHTU4C0yb7bIaMBpAFxILaW6W3lZsiCt=s150" title="Dentist in Westminster" alt="Dentist in Westminster">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="content">
            <a class="header" href="/vi/5870511561113600.html">Dentist in Westminster</a>
            <div class="meta">
              <span class="price"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="description">
              <p>Pari J. Moazed, DDS is a family dentist ...</p>
            </div>
            <div class="extra">
              <div class="ui label">
                Services
              </div>
              <div class="ui label">
                For sale
              </div>
              <div class="ui label">Baltimore</div>
              <div class="ui label">Maryland</div>
              <div class="ui right floated primary button">
                Buy now
                <i class="right chevron icon"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

This "solution" works, but I don't like it

`<div {% if loop.index0 == 0 %}style="margin-top:10px!important"{%  endif %} class="item">`

Comment: You could apply the margin top to the div.container

Comment: Your question doesn't make it clear why you don't like the solution. Is it the `!important` you don't like? And there's no way to remove it from the stylesheet, so you'd be able to simply override it without writing `!important` yourself?

Comment: Otherwise, use a margin or a padding on the list container, or write `.item:first-child`for a selector in your stylesheet.

Comment: Maybe I should try the tabs from semantic-ui. Right now I mix the twitter bootstrap tabs and the semantic-ui item lists. If I use only semantic-ui and not twitter bootstrap then the layout might go better.

Answer (score 2):

By the looks of it I would personally just change the margin on the  with the simple line:

```
.container .nav{
  margin-top:10px;
}
```

Does this answer your question? (I know it looks too simple to be true)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest adding a custom class to `<ul class='nav nav-tabs'>`

```
 <ul class="nav custom-class nav-tabs">
```

and adding margin-bottom to it

```
.custom-class{ 
    margin-bottom:20px;
 }
```

We are adding a custom class to unordered list `<ul>` so that changes made to it doesn't effect other elements which are using **nav** class

Answer (score 2):

On your ***div.tab-content*** try adding class ***ui basic segment***

Answer (score 0):

I know it is waaay overdue, but I came across this thread when looking for the same issue in Semantic UI React. My solution was to add a divider above the first container:

```
<Divider hidden></Divider>
```